# Loop for offset and limit in a request

Tags: php, api, loops, request

I need some help to make a loop to execute my request in api.
I have a request that is only permited requests with a limit and offset, but the request show only data every 100.
I set manually the limit to 100 and offset to 0, but i'll automate this request, so i need automate this too.
I need that the variable offset and limit sum 100 in the value and do the same request, but the variables changed.

Ex:
First request: offset = 0, limit = 100, Second request: offset = 100, limit = 200, Third request: offset = 200, limit = 300, Fourty request: offset = 300, limit = 400...

When the offset is 3000 i need to stop.

I use this variables in url_no = ...

```
$offset = 0; // Começa do registro 'x';
$limit = 100; // Vai até o registro 'x';

//Var URI:
    $url_no = "https://".$account['baseuri']."/messaging_history/api/account/".$account['id']."/conversations/search?offset=".$offset."&limit=".$limit;
```

Comment: So, you already know that you're looking for a loop; PHP has [while](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php), [do-while](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php), [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to choose from. It is also has [arithmetic operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for doing simple maths. Putting them together is one of the first things in many programming tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it right, i did this:

```
$request = 3000;

For($i=0 ;  $offset < $request ; $i++){
$limit = 100;
$offset = $limit*$i;
echo "<pre>";
echo $offset . " " .  $limit;
echo "</pre>";
}
```

And my result was:
[image: RESULT OF REQUEST]

Comment: This is not the desired result specified in the question.  If this is the correct answer then your question is Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should do it :

```
$limit = 100;

For($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($request) ; $i++){
$offset=$limit - 100;
$limit += 100;
echo $offset,$limit
}
```

Results:
0,100 100,200 200,300 ,...